# Spring Boot MVC application JSP not displaying

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot trying to write a MVC application using Spring boot. Control is coming to the controller but the JSP is not getting displayed. i have tried putting JSP in webapp folder, webapp/web-inf folder it did not work. below is the code.

application.properties:

```
server.port=8099
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /webapp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

LoginController:

```
    @Controller
    public class LoginController {  
        @RequestMapping("/login")
        public ModelAndView login(Model model) {
            System.out.println("*********************************");
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
            modelAndView.setViewName("welcome");
            return modelAndView;
        }
}
```

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oIAP.png)

Answer (score 0):

your jsp page is located in `WEB-INF`, so you need to change `prefix` to below so that it can view the jsp:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
```

and move your `welcome.jsp` to `jsp` folder.

Comment: tried that its not working. I have generated the project using spring initalizer

Comment: that's weird thing, have you clean up and rebuild it?And make sure to let all the jsp page located in jsp folder

Comment: @user3927150 Check `ModelAndView` is imported from `org.springframework.web.servlet`,if so and still not works ,then I have no idea

Comment: Yeah it is imported from org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView

Comment: @lucmt it has worked by adding jasper dependency in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

to

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Change prefix like below,

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
```

and move your `welcome.jsp` inside the `jsp` folder, per your project structure it is inside /WEB-INF/ folder, paraller to jsp folder.

Answer (score 0):

WE need to add embeded-jasper dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

in pom.xml and this dependency will not be there in the spring initialiser  generated project

Answer (score 0):

Change `spring.mvc.view.prefix: /webapp/` to `spring.mvc.view.prefix: /webapp/jsp/` and you are done!
The "/" at the end is very important.
You of course need to add the jasper dependeny to your pom:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
   <!-- scope must be as per default compile -->
   <!-- <scope>compile</scope>-->
</dependency>
```